# Solubility of silver chromate in ammonia

Tags: solubility

Does anyone know where I can find data on the solubility of silver chromate in an aqueous ammonia solution (100 mL) of concentration 2 mol/L at 25 C? Values for different concentration and temperature would also be helpful. I am solving problems in chemistry, so I am interested in whether the obtained value makes sense. Specifically, for the mass of silver chromate that can be dissolved in 100 g of an aqueous ammonia solution with a concentration of 2 mol/L at 25 C, I got about 6.7 g. I have no idea if this value is too high, too low, or possible. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Did you calculate it or measure? It's not 1:1 in moles - a quarter of that at best.

Comment: The Handbook of Chemistry and Physics states that $\ce{Ag2CrO4}$ is soluble in aqueous ammonia solutions.

Comment: @Mithoron I calculated it. However, I found a mistake in my calculations and now I got 15 g instead of 6.7 g.

Comment: Not much of a progress - it was already at least 4 times too much. BTW it can't be calculated - just an upper bound based on how the reaction goes.